# Framing painter's canvases (optimization or AI?)

Tags: php, perl, vbscript, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization

Here is a problem that I wld like to formulate:
The painter intends to frame his square canvases of different sizes in centimeters:

25cm x 35cm -- 20 pcs,
   50 x 30 -- 30 pcs,
   90 x 50 -- 40 pcs,
   110 x 60 -- 25 pcs,

The painter will purchase wooden stretcher bars of 200cm and cut them accordingly.
Condition is "each frame edge should be single continuous bar. No gluing".

Unlimited wooden stretcher bars available in length 200 cm.
how many bars of (200 cm) the Painter  should buy?
How to calculate the optimized number of bars, with least wastage of bars?

Is this problem related to optimization (mathematical programming) or AI?
PHP, Perl, vbscript codes welcome.

==============
For clarification purpose, here are the exact lengths to be produced from 200cm bars.

```
LENGTH      PIECES        TOTAL LENGTH 
110  cm      50   pcs      5500   cm
90   cm      80   pcs      7200   cm
60   cm      50   pcs      3000   cm
50   cm      140  pcs      7000   cm
35   cm      40   pcs      1400   cm
30   cm      60   pcs      1800   cm
25   cm      40   pcs      1000   cm
===========================================
            ALL TOTAL:     26900   cm
```

it is equal to 134.5 bars, if we were allowed to glue  small remaining pieces.

It will be practical to guide the painter what lengths should be cut from each bar.
Otherwise he will not know what to do with the bars supplied.

Comment: It's a mathematical programming problem. You need the optimal cutting list for the minimum number of 2m stock bars. I assume you're supposed to ignore the extra required for the corner mitres (i.e. the bars have an effective width of zero) so your cutting list is 40 x 25cm, 60 x 30cm, 40 x 35cm, 140 x 50cm, 50 x 60cm, 80 x 90cm, and 50 x 110cm

Comment: Please consider bars zero width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need width of stretcher bars to calculate length for angles (spending additional `2*$stretcher_width` for each side of canavas)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stretcher_length = 200;
my $stretcher_width = 0;
my $wasted_per_side = 2*$stretcher_width;
my @sc = (
   {w=> 25,  h=> 35, pcs=> 20},
   {w=> 50,  h=> 30, pcs=> 30},
   {w=> 90,  h=> 50, pcs=> 40},
   {w=> 110, h=> 60, pcs=> 25},
);
# all possible bars needed from longest to shortest
my @all = sort { $b <=> $a } map {
  (
    ($_->{w}+$wasted_per_side) x2, ($_->{h}+$wasted_per_side) x2
  )x $_->{pcs};
}
@sc;

# lets cut from 200cm bars
my @rest;
for my $len (@all) {

  my $cut_from;
  # do we already have bar which can be used?
  for my $len_have (@rest) {
    # yes, we have
    if ($len_have >= $len) { $cut_from = \$len_have; last; }
  }
  # no, we need another 200cm bar
  if (!$cut_from) {
    print "Taking new $stretcher_length cm bar\n";
    push @rest, $stretcher_length;
    $cut_from = \$rest[-1];
  }
  # cut it
  print "Now you have at least one bar $$cut_from long and cut away $len\n";
  $$cut_from -= $len;

  # keep @rest bars sorted from shortest to longest
  @rest = sort { $a <=> $b } @rest;
}

print scalar @rest;
# print "@rest\n"; # left overs
```

Comment: checking your code. in mean time the result of yr code is 116 bars. Actual length required for framing is 26900 cm = 134.5 bars, if we use single long bar, without waste.

Comment: @user3687431 http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f4c33f24-6f3d-47e4-bedd-6ec66d641302/view-source for no waste version. (set $stretcher_width to zero)

Comment: @user3687431 yes it is, it always looks for smallest reusable bar.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually cutting stock problem
[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)

There is a C implementation
[CPSOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)
Solves above problem with 135 sticks.

Unfortunately, failed to find a Perl implementation